# Print Barcode type as 'code128' not scanning in odoo

Tags: barcode, odoo-10

I have created a Product Code with some criteria..

My Barcode lenth is around 26-30 characters..

I can print barcode properly but when scan/ read it not getting value..

My BarCode:

```
 47789456789234/100001|417-19D
```

print_barcode.xml

```
   <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' %
   ('Code128', l.lot_id.name, 600, 100)"  
    style="width:300px;height:50px;"  />
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Barcode format to **EAN13** from **Code128**.

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' %('EAN13', l.lot_id.name, 600, 100)" style="width:300px;height:50px;" />
```